# Wrap ternary expression in React in function

Tags: reactjs, conditional-operator

In React, I often want to render something only when a condition is true. I used to do this, and it worked well:

```
return {condition?value:null}
```

Actual return expression is much more complicated, so a simple `if` statement would not do. But then I thought the `null` part was ugly, so I tried wrapping it in a function:

```
return {addIf(condition, value)}
```

Problem is, sometimes `value` uses what condition checks if is accessible. For example, `condition` would be like `player.hasOwnProperty(x)` and `value` would be `player.x`. This creates an error.

I think this is because value always evaluates in the latter. How can I achieve this? Is using ternary expressions with `null` the only way?

(I feel like what I really need is Lisp macro, but hopefully there's a much easier workaround.)

Comment: `{}` creates an object (and throws an error in your examples) you perhaps meant `return (...)`. For your second part I'm confused what's the question?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the actual code so it may be wrong. The question is, how can I do what ternary expression does, but without the `null`?

Comment: The answer below already gave the alternative. Function call would work as well but you'd have to do the conditional checkings inside `addIf` and then return its returned expression which is much more wordy than the ternary expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use the logical `&&` operator. Your solution will look like this:

```
return condition && value;
```

Comment: Ah right, I forgot about this one. Personally I don't prefer it (I have to do short circuit evaluation in my head every time), but it does look cleaner. I think I'll accept it if no one has a better answer.

Comment: Dont do this. if condition is 0, 0 will be dispalyed. https://medium.com/geekculture/stop-using-for-conditional-rendering-in-react-a0f7b96200f8

Comment: @mahan It looks like the problems only appear when `condition` is something other than boolean type. Is that correct?

Comment: If you may expect `condition` to be `0` (e.g. when using `array.length` as a condition) you may force it to boolean using `!!`, i.e. `return !!condition && value` or `return Boolean(condition) && value`

Comment: @ssamtkwon these are all particularly logically confusing things, however if the `condition` doesn't evaluate to `0` or `''`, you are good to use `&&`. For an `arr = []` don't use `arr.length` (which evaluates to a number) as a `condition` instead use `arr.length > 0` - which evaluates to a Boolean and you are all good. Booleans aren't rendered on the screen in React.

Answer (score 0):

It will work

```
return {condition?value:null}
```

Actual return expression is much more complicated, so a simple if statement would not do. But then I thought the null part was ugly, so I tried wrapping it in a function:

```
return {addIf(condition, value)}
```